# PySpark creates ticket___HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__ folder

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing files to S3 from spark dataframe created from HiveContext table, and getting an **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION** folder. What is this folder and how can I remove this?

Below is the line am using to do this,

```
my_df.write \
    .partitionBy("my_column") \
    .format("csv") \
    .bucketBy(1, "my_other_column") \
    .option("header", True)\
    .option("delimiter", my_delimiter) \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save("s3://my_bucket/my_folder/")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This means, your `partitionBy` column `my_column` has `null` value. Hive and in effect spark, by default writes it as `HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION`. The `ticket_` seems to be a string operation that you did with partition columns.

There are ways to remove this, but not without mutating/loosing data:
1. Do not write it in the first place, use some sensible value for `null`.
2. Drop the partition by altering the table.